# Nullity of a linear mapping composed with itself n times.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have a linear operator, $f$ from $V$ to $V$, and $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over some field $F$ and $f^n$ is the operator composed with itself n times and if there exists a positive integer m such that $$nullity(f^m)=nullity(f^{m+1}).$$ Why is it then true that $$nullity(f^m)=nullity(f^{m+k})$$ for all positive integer k?

I understand that this is likely to involve a proof by induction but I can't even verify it for k=2. I believe the solution should involve the rank-nullity theorem in some way. I understand there's also an inequality involving nullities of of compositions but I would like to avoid using that for now if possible.

I tried proving for k=2 by letting $n=dim(V)$ and then concluding that $$n=rank(f^m)+nullity(f^m)$$ $$n=rank(f^{m+1})+nullity(f^{m+1})$$ $$n=rank(f^{m+2})+nullity(f^{m+2})$$ and realized I can prove that they have equal rank to show they have equal nullity. So then I took $f_m$ which I defined as $f$ restricted to $f^m(V)$ and got $$dim(f^{m+1}(V))=rank(f^{m+1})=rank(f_{m+1})+nullity(f_{m+1})$$ and I believe $$rank(f_{m+1})=rank(f^{m+2})$$ because they are the same space but I don't know how to proceed after that.

Answer (score 1):

We are given that $f^mv=0\iff f^{m+1}v=0$.
Then for $k\ge0$, we have $f^{m+k}v=0\iff f^mf^kv=0\iff f^{m+1}f^kv=0\iff f^{m+k+1}v=0$. Hence $$f^mv=0\iff f^{m+1}v=0\iff f^{m+2}v=0\iff\ldots\iff f^{m+k}v=0$$
(where the "$\ldots$" mean that there is an induction involved)